# How to create a table in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am implementing coding related to Broadcast Receiver.

In side the Broadcast Receiver i am getting messages.

I want to create a table in Broadcast Receiver class and save the messages in side the table.

And i want to get the messages (stored in table) in another activity.

If any one has idea please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In BroadCast Receiver you dont have enough time to do it so you have to call an Intent and open an activity and Do whatever you want to do in that activity.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver - You should handle the events in a very short time span(~5secs) else it will give, ANR to the application.

Create a DatabaseAdapter, using that add the messages(ReceiverClass) to the Database, refer - http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

In the other Activity, use the DatabaseAdapter to query the messages which are written to the Database.

In case if you want Activity should know when ever ReceiverClass writes something to Database, use ContentObserver in the Activity.

for ContentObserver - http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html